# prevent javascript execution over file_get_contents

Tags: javascript, php, security, nginx

Is there a way to configure PHP/server (over Nginx php-fpm) to prevent javascript execution from php file_get_contents?

right now, if I allow users to upload html files with js embedded, JS get executed when file is displayed through file_get_contents() call.

I plan to add HTML filtering (ie deny html upload) but it will be even better if I can  have a second layer  of security on the ouput, instead of only on the upload (in case the first layer failed to take into account so scenario).

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to happen instead of executing the JS? Browsers are just going to treat it as executable by default - do you want to remove it entirely? Or just display the entire upload as escaped HTML?

Comment: if you don't want to allow html at all you can strip all html tags using `preg_replace("%</?[^>]+>%s", "", $file)`

Comment: In fact, what I am trying to do is work on file type blacklisting (as there is no whitelisting in that case) but still add additional security measures. I guess the best way in that case is to 
1) add some xss check to minimize potential vector of attacks
2) force content to be downloaded through  something like

<?php 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($target)); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kudos to jcubic for providing a link to an explanation of why his solution won't work ;)

There are only 2 robust solutions I know of:

1) use a markup language other than HTML which has a provable grammar and does not allow embedded scripting (BBCode?). This [still requires that you validate the submission](http://jeffchannell.com/Other/bbcode-xss-howto.html) for compliance - but is simpler than for HTML.

2) apply a [content security policy](https://content-security-policy.com/) which does not allow inline javascript - this would be my preferred solution, not least because you can specify a reporting URL, allowing you to police what is happenning on the browser rather than relying on filtering on the server.

Comment: Thanks symcbean. 

In the end, I will go with 
1) having a pre-xss filtering to display message to end users if file as some script tags that should not be there 
2) make content  forced to be download
3) adding the CSP to  "default-src 'none';";

(3) is what I was missing and that is the perfect solution as I have a specific sub-domain for the content to be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to strip JavaScript before you echo the content of the file:

```
echo preg_replace("%<script[^>]*>.*</script>%si", "", file_get_contents());
```

or you can call this when you upload the file so you don't have to do that each time.

you may also want to remove events like onclick and style that have url with `javascript:` protocol, to remove those you probably be better with a xml parser.

Here is a list of XSS vectors attacks that you can take into account: [XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet)